# How the CMP instruction uses condition flags?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to figure out the behavior of conditional jumps (JE/JNE, JZ/JNZ) in the x86 instruction set familly.

Which condition flags `CMP` instruction sets and **how**, if the result is equal and if it is not? For example:

- `CMP eax, 0` (true)
- `CMP eax, 0` (false)

Comment: You could get that information from the first results from DuckDuckGo (or Google (or Bing)). Did you tried that?

Comment: Yes I did. (Google). Found a lot, what jumps read, but not exactly what CMP sets.

Comment: `CMP` sets all the flags based on the intermediate results of `SUB` that it performs. read here: http://www.godevtool.com/GoasmHelp/usflags.htm

Comment: (CMP EAX,EDX;set zero flag if eax=edx.) So only the zero flag and if true 1 and false 0. Tanks.

Comment: read `cmp` documentation first: [*The comparison is performed by subtracting the second operand from the first operand and then setting the status flags in the **same manner as the `SUB` instruction**.*](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp). But that's not a good way to [check whether a register is zero or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33721204/995714)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Furthermore, with the CMP instruction, the destination operand doesn't change. Just the flags.

Let me illustrate. Let's say `EAX = 00000005` and `EBX = 00000005`. If we do this arithmetic operation:

`CMP EAX, EBX`

What's happening, is in effect this:

`EAX - EBX` ---->
`00000005 - 00000005`

Since the result would be `0`, but we don't change the destination operand in a CMP instruction, the zero flag is set to `1` (since it's true).

So, as we saw, depending on the result of the previous arithmetic operation, flags can be set accordingly:

[image]

Comment: Presumably, where values are signed and of opposite signs (because the CPU doesn't have a way to distinguish signed from unsigned) that use of the C flag isn't true  - so 0xff > 0x01 makes it also look like -1 > 1. I expect in that case you'd check the S flag which is true if the result would be negative.

Answer (score 4):

The `CMP` instruction does internally a `SUB` and sets the flags accordingly.

So all flags that are set by a `SUB` are also set by `CMP`.

Namely the flags `SF`, `ZF`, `AF`, `PF`, and `CF` are set.

This information is taken from the Intel manual for the processors (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm).